# How to turn off code coverage in SonarQube 4?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jmockit, jacoco

How to turn off code coverage in SonarQube 4? I have JMockit usage in unit tests and JaCoCo code coverage plugin in Sonar. They conflict because they use different javaagents to edit bytecode of classes (as I know). I want to switch off code coverage in Sonar. I can exclude my project in settings of Jacoco, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the paragraph "Ignore Code Coverage" in this documentation:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus